# how create a view class include all function in django view

Tags: django

For example i have a admin app in a django project. I have 2 view function in views.py like as

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Manager
def admin_home(request):
    manager = 'manager'
    context ={
        'manager':manager,
    }
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', context) 



def admin_show(request):
    manager = Manager.objects.all()
    context ={
        'manager':manager,
    }
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
```

But i want to write both function in a class. like as

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Manager
from django.views import View

class AdminPart(View):
    def admin_home(request):
        manager = 'manager'
        context ={
            'manager':manager,
        }
        return render(request, 'home/index.html', context) 



    def admin_show(request):
        manager = Manager.objects.all()
        context ={
            'manager':manager,
        }
        return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
```

Isn't it possible in django like as python class. please help me....

Answer (score 0):

There are class based views in Django.

Here read the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/

or maybe try this tut:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tqhhT3R6VY

Hope this helps! (:

Comment: An example here in this Answer would be helpful. Preferably tailored to answer the Question. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Django rest framework, it provides many feature-rich types of class-based views like generic api view, viewset
[https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/](http://django%20rest%20class%20based%20view)